# How can I fetch an image to appear on a blog page from an external folder in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, image

I am trying to fetch an image from a MySQL database on my blog page. The image was inserted to the database using a reporter page that has the image/ folder. On the blog page I don't have the image/ folder. Could you please advise me on how I can  display the image on my blog page from the external image folder?

```
<?php 
$breakingNews = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM breaking_news WHERE status = 1");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($breakingNews)){
        $banner = $row['image_banner'];
        $title = $row['title'];
        $description = $row['description'];
        $category = $row['category'];

        ?>
            <article class="blog_style1">
                <div class="blog_img">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="<?php echo $banner; ?>" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="blog_text">
                    <div class="blog_text_inner">
                        <a class="cat" href="#"><?php echo $category; ?></a>
                        <a href="view.php"><h4>Breaking news: <?php echo $title; ?></h4></a>
                        <p><?php echo $description; ?></p>
                        <div class="date">
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> March 14, 2018</a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 05</a>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>
        <?php
    }

?>
```

Comment: If the image url is `www.website.it/image/image.jpg` just use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/'.$row['image_banner']`

Comment: *"The image was inserted to the database using a reporter page that has the image/ folder. On the blog page I don't have the image/ folder."* - Why did you use it in the first place?